# Get how object is named from the object

Tags: c#

Is is posible to get how you named object from the object

For example:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Test testVariable = new Test();
}
```

```
class Test
{
    public Test()
    {
         Console.WriteLine(GetName());
    }
}
```

would be **testVariable**

Comment: Not possible. `testVariable` is not the name of the object, but the name of the variable. Objects don't naturally have names.

Comment: You'd have to pass more information to the constructor in order to do this.  A better question is why do you need to do this?  This sounds like an XY question where you're asking about the solution you're attempting instead of what you need this solution for.

Comment: Look like you try to get the variable name instead? [`nameof(testVariable)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/nameof). This `nameof`  can only be used within the same cope with the variable. Will be better try to explain more on what you want to achieve.

Comment: You can't. Imagine you doing the following `Test test2 = testvariable`, ie both variables are pointing to the very same object. What would your results be?

Comment: @YongShun That would only work within the same scope, or you'd have to store the resulting value somewhere.

Comment: @yongshun even if it's possible, what sense would `nameof(testvariable)` make? You will need to know at compile time what variable to put into `nameof`. And the moment you know which variable to put in, you also know the result. The only possible result of `nameof(testvariable)` is `"testvariable"` but you don't need `nameof` for that ...

Comment: Ya, my previous comment not detailed enough. The nameof only works within same scope. Not sure Post Owner try to attempt.

Answer (score 2):

From your code example, it looks like you want the name of the assigned variable. This is not possible without specific requirements on the caller.

There is no real robust solution in C# for this.

The best you can do is using the [`nameof` expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/nameof):

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Test testVariable = new Test(nameof(testVariable));
}

class Test
{
    public Test(string variableName)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(variableName);
    }
}
```

However, this will add little benefit. As you can see, it is a 'static' solution in that it requires to pass in the name of the variable at compile time. Using `nameof` makes this 'refactor friendly' and gives you basic compile time checking:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Test testVariable = new Test(nameof(tstVariable)); // compiler error
}
```

It opens scenarios like this:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Test testVariable1 = new Test(nameof(testVariable1));
    Test testVariable2 = new Test(nameof(testVariable2)); 
}
```

But as mentioned, this doesn't add very much value, and it's still error prone. For example, nothing stops you from doing something like this:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Test testVariable1 = new Test(nameof(testVariable1));
    Test testVariable2 = new Test(nameof(testVariable1)); // oops, should be testVariable2
}
```

Also, as @derpirscher points out, it doesn't stop you from things like this:

```
Test testVariable1 = new Test(nameof(testVariable1));
Test testVariable2 = testVariable1;
testVariable2.Test(); // still outputs "testVariable1"
```

Comment: What's the real benefit of `nameof` here? With `new Test(nameof(testVariable1))` you already know at compiletime that the result is `"testVariable1"` so you can just pass the string `"testVariable1"` as parameter without `nameof`. he only (yet quite small) benefit of using `nameof` is, that you can be sure, that variable currently exists in the scope (but not necessarily is the var you are assigning to ...). Furthermore if you do `Test testVariable2 = testVariable1;` then `testVariable2.Test()` will still print `"testVariable1"` so what benefit does this additional parameter have at all? T

Comment: @derpirscher I think your concerns were already largely covered in my answer. The benefit is indeed very small. Good point on assigning testVariable1 to testVariable2 - will add that.